# Getting a syntax error when trying to add two global variables in a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a russian roulette game, and I keep getting an error on one specific line of code. I've done some research and can't figure out what's wrong. I get the invalid syntax error on the += part of the line

```
global pot += global aibet
```

Not sure why this is happening? Here's the rest of my code for context:

```
import random

pot = 0
playerbudget = 500
aibudget = 500
playerbet = 0
aibet = 0
deathspin = 6


def AIbet():
    print()
    aibet = random.randint(50,250)
    print("The AI bets: $",aibet,sep="")

def AIspin():
    print()
    print("The AI spins the chamber...")
    print("...And pulls the trigger.")
    print()
    dead = 6

if dead == deathspin:
    print("The AI lands on the bad cartridge")
    print()
    global pot += global aibet
    aibudget -= aibet
    print("The pot is currently: $",pot,sep="")
    print("The AI has a hand of $",aibudget,".",sep="")
```

Comment: I believe that use of `global` is unnecessary. Is there any reason why you’re using a bunch of global variables and printing instead of functions which take/return values?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, how would I return the number to the variable outside of the function?

Comment: For which function? It might help if you explain what the program is meant to do, and I can post that in an answer.

Comment: I thought I explained that, but here goes: THe program is meant to simulate a gambling game in which an ai makes a bet, and the player can choose to make a bet or fold. If the player folds, a random number is chosen and if it is picked, then the ai loses the amount of money that they bet and it goes into a pot. I would like to return the new values for aibet, pot, and aibudget.

Comment: _If the player folds, a random number is chosen and if it is picked, then the ai loses_ There are two numbers generated? The aim of the game is just to guess the number 1-6? I'm still not sure I understand, a bunch of things remain unexplained. My question simply was: What are the rules of the game, how does it work?

Comment: I guess you dont understand Russian Roulette then. Each player can bet any amount, then they essentially roll the dice. If the dice lands on a certain, number, they lose the amount they betted and it is added to to the pot.

Comment: I thought Russian Roulette involves a gun, you can't lose twice ;) Just to ensure I understand this correctly: A random number is generated. Each player bets a certain amount that their random roll will be equal to that target number. Then, they each roll for a number. If they win, they get the pot, otherwise, they add their bet to the pot. Is that correct?

Comment: What happens if, say, the second player out of 4 rolls and wins. Do the remaining two automatically lose? This is assuming there is some sort of order to the rolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of global is not correct when you say `global pot += global aibet`

Using the `global` keyword inside a lower scope (like a function or a class) tells python to use the global version of that variable and not the local version. (You can access a dictionary of the global variables using `globals()`).

This means that in every function you modify `pot` and `aibet`, you need to declare the variable as `global` before you use it.

This can get messy and the use of `global` variables like this is frowned upon unless absolutely necessary (which for your case it is NOT necessary).

So first, in order to fix your issue, you will need to:

1. Add this to your `AIbet` function before you use either variable. Remember, this is telling the interpreter to use the global version of these variables instead of the local version.

```py
global pot
global aibet
```

2. Add this to your `AIspin` function. You use `dead` in the `if` statement in the global scope later in your code, so `dead` also needs to be `global`.

```py
global dead
```

3. I'm speculating that your `if dead == deathspin:` statement should be indented and inside the `AIspin` function. If this is the case, the only changes you have to make is to add global declarations for `pot`, `aibet`, and `aibudget` like you did for `dead` and replace `global pot += global aibet` with `pot += aibet`. Doing so gives us this for your `AIspin` function:

```
def AIspin():
    global dead
    global pot
    global aibet
    global aibudget
    print()
    print("The AI spins the chamber...")
    print("...And pulls the trigger.")
    print()
    dead = 6

    if dead == deathspin:
        print("The AI lands on the bad cartridge")
        print()
        pot += aibet
        aibudget -= aibet
        print("The pot is currently: $",pot,sep="")
        print("The AI has a hand of $",aibudget,".",sep="")
```

But don't you think this looks bad and is riddled with unnecessary `global` statements? Instead, adapt a `class` based approach where you don't need to pass around so many global variables. It would look like this:

```py
import random

class RussianRoulette:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pot = 0
        self.playerbudget = 500
        self.aibudget = 500
        self.playerbet = 0
        self.aibet = 10
        self.deathspin = 6
        self.dead = 6

    def ai_bet(self):
        print()
        self.aibet = random.randint(50,250)
        print(f"The AI bets: ${self.aibet:.2f}")
        return

    def ai_spin(self):
        print()
        print("The AI spins the chamber...")
        print("...And pulls the trigger.")
        print()
        if self.dead == self.deathspin:
            print("The AI lands on the bad cartridge")
            print()
            self.pot += self.aibet
            self.aibudget -= self.aibet
            print(f"The pot is currently: ${self.pot:.2f}")
            print(f"The AI has a hand of ${self.aibudget:.2f}")
        return
```

You would then use this class like this:

```
game = RussianRoulette()
game.ai_spin()
game.ai_spin()
game.ai_spin()
```

Which outputs:

```
The AI spins the chamber...
...And pulls the trigger.

The AI lands on the bad cartridge

The pot is currently: $10.00
The AI has a hand of $490.00

The AI spins the chamber...
...And pulls the trigger.

The AI lands on the bad cartridge

The pot is currently: $20.00
The AI has a hand of $480.00

The AI spins the chamber...
...And pulls the trigger.

The AI lands on the bad cartridge

The pot is currently: $30.00
The AI has a hand of $470.00
```

Summary: Avoid using `global` and use a class approach if possible. You can pack "shared" variables into your class instance. The class instance acts like a container for your variables (in your case). We can access the variables anywhere within the class' methods by prepending the variable name with `self` (assuming that's what you named the first argument).

Consider reading:

1. [Easy to follow tutorial on python classes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp)
2. [Official documentation on python classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. The names aren’t even internally consistent here.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how global works. Try this:

```
global pot 
global aibet
pot += aibet
```

Comment: Could you explain what global actually does then?

Comment: `global` makes python look for the name in globals not locals: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python

Comment: @SyntaxVoidsupportsMonica, the purpose of the global is to have the variable remain constant whether it is being used in a function or outside fo a function.